# New to Bash. Can't pass arguments to the bash script

Tags: bash

```
echo $1 $2 $3 ' -> echo $1 $2 $3'
args=("$@")
echo ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} ' -> args=("$@"); echo ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}'
echo $@ ' -> echo $@'
echo Number of arguments passed: $# ' -> echo Number of arguments passed: $#'
```

This is suppose to be the output

[image: This is suppose to be the output]

But I get this instead.

```
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:bash jasonkim$ bash arguments.sh 
 -> echo $1 $2 $3
 -> args=("$@"); echo ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}
 -> echo $@
Number of arguments passed: 0  -> echo Number of arguments passed: $#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that you can't, it's that you *didn't*.

```
bash arguments.sh Bash Scripting Tutorial
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

$ ./scr.sh a b c

outputs :

```
a
b
c
```

- And yes, OBVIOUSLY the error is that you didn't pass any parameters to script at all... Maybe try running : `bash arguments.sh arg1 arg2 arg3` ?

Comment: `"$@"` is the default target for `for`.

Comment: Good point. I was just trying to explain it in an "readable" way... ;-)