# Passing string variable to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script contains this condition

```
 if [ -z "${PEER_ADDRESS}" ]; then
    ##some code here
fi
```

I'm not able to pass PEER_ADDRESS variable when I run the script.

I tried the below but it always executed the if code

```
./script.sh PEER_ADDRESS="someString" 
./script.sh $1 ="someString" 
./script.sh "someString"
./script.sh $PEER_ADDRESS="someString"
```

Comment: Please research other available solutions before asking. You want to run your third example in "what you tried", then the passed arg will be available in `$1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732385, or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290 for a key=value notation being handled (it's just string processing; there's no magic "keyword args" function for passing things to Bash).

Comment: Note that your first attempt would work if you set the `-k` option first.

Comment: Hi @chepner,It didn't work also

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't work"? If you run `./script.sh "someString"`, then `"$1"` within that script will certainly expand to `someString`, and a question that claims otherwise should include a [mcve] allowing others to see the problem for themselves.

Comment: I stated in my question very clearly how the script referenced the variable..like this "${PEER_ADDRESS}" , that's why this way didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment precedes the command:

```
PEER_ADDRESS="someString" ./script.sh
```